# Insert values from stored procedure into table using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, linq, sqlbulkcopy

I'm having trouble with transferring data from a stored procedure into a real table by using `SqlBulkCopy`.

In the stored procedure, I create a temporary table and then insert values from many table into it.

In stored procedure:

```
-- Ex 1: 
CREATE TABLE #result (name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO #result
    SELECT name FROM dbo.Student
...
SELECT * FROM #result

-- Ex 2: 
DECLARE @result(name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #result
    SELECT name FROM dbo.Student
...
SELECT * FROM @result

-- Ex3: //use store select directly without using temporary table
SELECT name FROM dbo.Student

-- Ex4: //use function, in function I wrote exactly in storeP of Ex1 or Ex2
SELECT name FROM fnc_myfunction
```

Code:

```
conn.Open();
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

string csvConnString1 = "MySource";
OleDbDataAdapter oleda1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("exec my_storeP")", csvConnString1);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
oleda1.Fill(dt1);

using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Class";
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "StudentName");
    copy.WriteToServer(dt1);
}

Console.WriteLine("SqlBulkCopy: {0}", watch.Elapsed);
```

However, I cannot finished because it cannot mapping any "name" in store by Ex1 and Ex2, but it run by Ex3 and Ex4.

What should I do for Ex1 and Ex2 right now?

Comment: **WHY** are you sending the data back to the client, just to turn around and send it back to the server again with `SqlBulkCopy`?? Why can't that stored procedure to do `INSERT` itself, directly, all on the server, without any loads of data being transferred to the client, and then right back to the server .......

Comment: Because I have to get values from others DB on others server. Then I can't insert directly on only 1 server. I tried to using Job to push DB every day but it's not effect because my report run like a clock as realtime.